# How to make a Wordpress filter/action using functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm pretty useless at creating filters and action in Wordpress functions.php.

Here's my request..

I wish to change 2 lines to code, without changing the core theme files.

This is the code -

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sf_portfolio_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function sf_portfolio_thumbnail( $display_type = "gallery", $multi_size = "", $multi_size_ratio = "1/1", $columns = "2", $hover_show_excerpt = "no", $excerpt_length = 20, $gutters = "yes", $fullwidth = "no" ) {`

        global $post, $sf_options;

        $portfolio_thumb = $thumb_image_id = $thumb_image = $thumb_gallery = $video = $item_class = $link_config = $port_hover_style = $port_hover_text_style = '';
        $thumb_width     = 400;
        $thumb_height    = 300;
        $video_height    = 300;

        if ( $columns == "1" ) {
            $thumb_width  = 1200;
            $thumb_height = 900;
            $video_height = 900;
        } else if ( $columns == "2" ) {
            $thumb_width  = 800;
            $thumb_height = 600;
            $video_height = 600;
        } else if ( $columns == "3" || $columns == "4" ) {
            if ( $fullwidth == "yes" ) {
                $thumb_width  = 500;
                $thumb_height = 375;
                $video_height = 375;
            } else {
                $thumb_width  = 400;
                $thumb_height = 300;
                $video_height = 300;
            }
        }
```

This is the line I wish to change.

```
        } else if ( $columns == "2" ) {
            **$thumb_width  = 1280;
            $thumb_height = 1024;**
            $video_height = 600;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Did you try changing it?

Answer (score 0):

Its petty simple, you just modify your code to apply some filter like this

```
$thumb_width    = apply_filter( 'thumb_width', 800 ); // here 'thumb_width' is the filter name, which can be hooked on. and 800 is the default value.
$thumb_height   = apply_filter( 'thumb_height', 600 );
$video_height   = apply_filter( 'video_height', 600 );
```

Now you can use the filters in functions.php to modify the values.

You can copy and paste below code into your functions.php

```
add_filter('thumb_width', 'my_custom_thumb_width', 10, 1); //'10' is the priority of the filter if hooked multiple time. lower numbered one will be executed first. '1' is the number of argument passed.
function my_custom_thumb_width($thumb_width){
    $thumb_width = 1280; //modify the value as your requirement
    return $thumb_width;
}

add_filter('thumb_height', 'my_custom_thumb_height', 10, 1);
function my_custom_thumb_width($thumb_width){
    $thumb_height = '1024'; //modify the value as your requirement
    return $thumb_height;
}

add_filter('video_height', 'my_custom_video_height', 10, 1);
function my_custom_thumb_width($thumb_width){
    $video_height = '600'; //modify the value as your requirement
    return $video_height;
}
```

Comment: OP need without changing core files

Comment: You may need to go for child theme then. If so you can directly use your new value there, no need to go for filters

Comment: You can refer here to know more about to create a child theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Thanks, this returns a fatal error, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

When you come to write a function in your child theme which you want to override the one in the parent theme, you just give it the same name as the one in the parent theme:

```
function sf_portfolio_thumbnail($display_type = "gallery", $multi_size = "", $multi_size_ratio = "1/1", $columns = "2", $hover_show_excerpt = "no", $excerpt_length = 20, $gutters = "yes", $fullwidth = "no") {

    global $post, $sf_options;

    $portfolio_thumb = $thumb_image_id = $thumb_image = $thumb_gallery = $video = $item_class = $link_config = $port_hover_style = $port_hover_text_style = '';
    $thumb_width = 400;
    $thumb_height = 300;
    $video_height = 300;

    if ($columns == "1") {
        $thumb_width = 1200;
        $thumb_height = 900;
        $video_height = 900;
    } else if ($columns == "2") {
        $thumb_width = 800;
        $thumb_height = 600;
        $video_height = 600;
    } else if ($columns == "3" || $columns == "4") {
        if ($fullwidth == "yes") {
            $thumb_width = 500;
            $thumb_height = 375;
            $video_height = 375;
        } else {
            $thumb_width = 400;
            $thumb_height = 300;
            $video_height = 300;
        }
    } else if ($columns == "2") {
        $thumb_width = 1280;
        $thumb_height = 1024;
        $video_height = 600;
    }
}
```

WordPress will run the function in the [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) first, and when it comes to the one in the parent theme, it'll check if it already exists and because it does, it won't run it.

Happy Coding!!